# Give a supremum of any two interger?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume $x,y \in N^{+} $ with $ x y = C  $,where $ C \in N = {2,3,...} $ is constant,please give a supremum
\begin{equation}
d_{max} = \sup_{x,y \in N^{+}}|x - y |
\end{equation}

Firstly,i am sorry for its incomplete.

Secondly,I want to give my additional information for this question.When i try to transform a  multiply array $S={S_{i_{1}i_{2}...i_{k}} | i_{1} = 1,2,...,n_{1},...,i_{k} = 1,2,...,n_{k} }$ to a matrix $ A = (a_{ij})_{m \times n}$ by the indices and then define the  eigenvalues, determinant and rank of $S$,but it looks good so far.

Comment: Are you able to solve this yourself for a specific constant, say $C=10$?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking "given $C$, find the smallest $x$ such that $x$ divides $C$, then compute $|C/x-x|$." The actual smallest is, as others have said, $x=1$, in which case the difference is $C-1$. When $C$ is prime this is the only possibility. If you are excluding this trivial case, then there is no simple formula, because any such simple formula would generate a fast prime factorization algorithm. Specifically, if you know $C$ and $C/x-x$, then you can solve a quadratic equation to find $x$, which gets you the smallest prime factor of $C$. Repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by $N^+$ you mean the positive integers, wouldn't this just be $C-1$, i.e. $x=1$ and $y=C$?

Comment: Yes,don't consider the triviality.

Answer (score 0):

If $xy=C$, then the lowest possible value of $x$ is $1$, then $y=C$. If $x$ takes on larger values, then $y$ must have lower values, hence the difference will be lower. Hence the max is obtained for $x=1,y=C$ or $x=C,y=1$.

Comment: This is triviality.

Comment: @askuyue What did you expect?

Comment: In fact, I want to get $ inf_{x,y \in N^{+}} |x-y|$,but by using simple example,i can't get what i want.Then i want to check what is $sup_{x,y \in N^{+} } |x-y|$?

Comment: @askuyue Ok, you want the inf, ask for the sup, and you are not satisfied that yo got the sup? Is this just some troll?

Comment: @askuyue Identifying the inf (which is just a min, by the way, because every natural number has only finitely many divisors) would again generate a fast prime factorization algorithm, which is generally accepted to be impossible. (This hasn't been proven, but it hinges on the P=NP problem.)

Comment: Firstly,i am sorry for its incomplete.

Secondly,I want to give my additional information for this question.When i try to transform a  multiply array $S={S_{i_{1}i_{2}...i_{k}} | i_{1} = 1,2,...,n_{1},...,i_{k} = 1,2,...,n_{k} }$ to a matrix $ A = (a_{ij})_{m \times n}$ by the indices and define the  eigenvalues, determinant and rank of $S$,but it looks good so far.